# got error when i try to install my WebService on Windows-XP

Tags: web-services, installation, windows-installer

i try to install my WebService on Windows-XP,

and i got this error:

```
The installation of 
C:\MyWS\MyWS_Setup.msi
is not permitted due to an error in software restriction policy processing.
The object cannot be trusted
```

what can be the problem ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run regedit and verify that there are no policy restrictions disabling installer under this key:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer]

If there are, just right click on them and delete them. A reboot may be necessary.

The restriction name would be "DisableMsi"

Also, as a test, if you are logging in as Administrator in Safe Mode -- could you try creating a new User Account and giving it Administrative rights and test these issues under the new account in normal mode?

One more thing, just to make sure the account you are having problems with in "normal" mode really has administrative rights, would you right click on the Start tab and see if "open" and "explore" "All Users" is present?